# Métodos __str__ e __unicode__

Tags: python, django

Já vi códigos de classes que implementam modelos Django sobrescrevendo tanto o método `__str__` como o `__unicode__`, há diferença entre eles? Se sim, existe algum caso que devo preferir um no lugar de outro?

Comment: Você está usando Python 2 ou 3? Eu peguei problemas com versão do Python com isso; quando eu estava estudando Django, fiz [um projeto](https://github.com/jeffque/exam_maker) e passei por essa dúvida; creio que em algum momento eu tenha comitado algo explicando essa mudança

Comment: Parece que foi [nesse commit](https://github.com/jeffque/exam_maker/commit/908aa2781d92e51bbc8047aedd702b2483e6ce27) que eu fiz essa mudança

Comment: Estou usando Python 3.

Comment: Se vocẽ está usando Python 3 não precisa nem do método  `__unicode__`(nunca) e nem das chamadas a `encode` que por acaso voce encontrar dentro de códigos antigos do `__str__`.

Comment: Obrigado @jsbueno.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> há diferença entre eles?

`__str__()` é uma forma mais antiga (devolve bytes). `__unicode__()` é uma forma nova (devolve caracteres, normalmente em UTF-8).

No Django, é uma boa prática fazer `__str__()` também devolver Unicode se você usa o Python 2:

```
def __str__(self):
    return unicode(self).encode('utf-8')
```

[Pela documentação](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/python3/#str-and-unicode-methods), `__unicode__()` é chamado primeiro. Se não existir, `__str__()` é chamado.

> Se sim, existe algum caso que devo preferir um no lugar de outro?

Para Python 2, em que o unicode não é garantido de forma transparente, `__unicode__()` é preferível de ser usado.

Para Python 3, `__str__()` já é naturalmente unicode, então não há necessidade de ter ambos.

Comment: Acho que o que você falou sobre retornar bytes é válido para  Python2; entendi outra coisa lendo a documentação disso no [Python3](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__)

Comment: Na verdade, me confundi ainda mais ao ler a documentação no Python2...

Comment: No link que você mencionou diz "In Python 3, there’s simply __str__(), which must return str (text)", depois de ler na documentação esta afirmação, fiquei confuso com a parte que você diz que __str__() é uma forma mais antiga e __unicode__() é uma forma mais nova...

Comment: Moral da história? Em Python3 ignore o `__unicode__`?

Comment: Acho que vocês estão complicando muito. Python 3 trabalha com unicode de forma mais transparente, enquanto que no Python 2 a string é uma representação em bytes, não necessariamente em unicode. Eu posso acrescentar isso na resposta se vocês quiserem.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez seria ótimo, por favor

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, muito obrigado